WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type in selenium webdriver
I am unable to solve the WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type error and tried in many ways.
My code:
package selenium;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
         
         WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
         driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/");
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}


I have Configured Java21, Selenium 4.27 and Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components) Version: 2024-12 (4.34.0)


[![Error screenshot of Could not start a new session][4]][4]

You have no import for WebDriver class, and may not have fixed the project Build Path for same

yes in my project don't have import but how to resolve this please? and jars are added in  java build path for this project.

Click the red x on the left of the same line. IDE will give you advice. You can also add a new line "import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver" before the class definition.

Yes i tried but it was not showing. Attached the screenshot. Suspecting some jars could be missing and i tried in may ways.

You should use Maven project what has pom.xml . You add dependency
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.27.0</version>
</dependency>

You can folk https://github.com/bonigarcia/selenium-examples.git ,
or download this project https://github.com/willysalazar/selenium-webdriver-java-example/archive/refs/heads/master.zip

You are probably missing the JAR.
You can download that JAR here and link that with your project:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.27.0
I recommend using Maven for managing your project's external dependencies. It is very popular for Java. Your IDE should be able to generate a basic Maven java project. You will have to refer to the Maven manual for more info.
